# I am using forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField in django admin and I am want to show a python list saved in database as text

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

models.py

```
dummyColumnName = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name="MyCrazyIdea",db_column='dummy_column_name')
```

In Database the values are stored as

```
u'[1L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 74L, 84L, 86L, 87L, 133L, 134L, 137L, 142L]
```

forms.py

```
    dummyColumnName = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=get_queryset(),
                label = "My Crazy Idea/s",
                widget = FilteredSelectMultiple("My Crazy Idea/s", is_stacked=False),
                required = False)
```

I want the right side of this FilteredSelect Box to show the values in list one below another

Right now, If I save 142 in database like u'[142L]', it is shown as

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: That's a very odd way to store the data. Are you just saving the str() of a list? Why?

Comment: @Daniel I agree that this is not the right way. However I cannot change the database design. Is there a way to work this out !

Comment: Are you storing it like the literal string `'u[142L]'`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes its stored like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own custom form field, which subclasses forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField and defines the to_python and prepare_value methods. Something like:

```
import ast

class StrModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def to_python(self, value):
         value = ast.literal_eval(value)
         return super(StrModelMultipleChoiceField, self).to_python(value)

    def prepare_value(self, value):
         value = (super(StrModelMultipleChoiceField, self).prepare_value(value)
         return unicode(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. Lemme check this !

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman prepare_value method is being called but not the to_python method. Is there something we need to do